# How to read title or body of a push notification in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, apple-push-notifications

Hello I am trying to read the title or body variable of my push notification in swift. For testing purposes I created a .apns file which I run with xcrun

The apns file looks like this:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "Dein Freund ist am Joggen",
            "body" : "Schick ihm ne Anfrage bro ",
            "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
        },
        "badge" : 5
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
}
```

This is the function I have for push notification presses. Userinfo is the complete message and it returns the output below this code. Now I need the .title or .body variable how can I get them ?

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    
    let application = UIApplication.shared
     
     if(application.applicationState == .active){
       //Prints the message when user tapped the notification bar when the app is in foreground
       print(userInfo)
       //Get the title of userInfo
     }
     
     if(application.applicationState == .inactive)
     {
       print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in background")
     }

    completionHandler()
  }
```

Output of userInfo:

```
[AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        "action-loc-key" = PLAY;
        body = "Schick ihm ne Anfrage bro ";
        title = "Dein Freund ist am Joggen";
    };
    badge = 5;
}, AnyHashable("acme2"): <__NSArrayM 0x6000000105d0>(
bang,
whiz
)
,
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code to extract both *title* and *body* from `userInfo` dictionary:

```
let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: Any]
let alert = aps?["alert"] as? [String: String]
let title = alert?["title"]
let body = alert?["body"]
print(title ?? "nil")
print(body ?? "nil")
```

**Update**: If you want to use `Codable` to map all the possible fields, it's slightly more difficult.

You can create a model like this:

```
struct Payload: Decodable {
    let aps: APS
    let acme1: String?
    let acme2: [String]?
}

struct APS: Decodable {
    let alert: Alert
    let badge: Int?
}

struct Alert: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let body: String?
    let action: String?
}
```

Then, you have to convert the `userInfo` dictionary back to `Data`, using `JSONSerialization` and finally decode the data using `JSONDecoder`:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userInfo)
    let payload = try decoder.decode(Payload.self, from: data)
    print(payload.aps.alert.title)
    print(payload.aps.alert.body ?? "nil")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was searching for